# how to search by included model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

```
let find_Query = {
  attributes: ["id"],
  include: [
    {
      model: Tender_details,
      include: [{
          model: Categories,attributes: ["id","category_name"],
          where:{}
        },
        {
          model: SubCategories,attributes: ["id","sub_category_name"],
          where:{}
        }
      ],
      where: {}
    },
  ],
  where: {}   };


switch (key) {
 case "search":
   find_Query.include[0].where[Op.or] = [
   {
      "$Categories.category_name$": {
          [Op.like]: `%${req.query.search}%`
       }
    },
    {
      "$Subcategories.sub_category_name$": {
          [Op.like]: `%${req.query.search}%`
       }
    }
   ];
  break;
default: 
  break;
```

I have used this code. In this code, i'm using [Op.or]. but it's not working properly.

In this code, i want to find data by **category_name** and **sub_category_name** from included model

Comment: What error did you get? Indicate it in your post

Comment: " Unknown column 'SpreeCategories.category_name' in 'on clause' ". i'm facing this error

Comment: Please add association definitions for models in the question